# Does a PC with many NIC's can create vulnerabilities for each network wihich it is connected?

Tags: risk

I wonder if installing 2 more (USB to Ethernet) NICs to my PC can be risky if I need that only my PC can access to the three networks, and no any other host in these networks... Could my PC act like a router, allowing traffic from any host to any network?

Comment: Yes. That is called a pivot point. Yet, it does not _create_ vulnerabilities per se, it „just“ makes them accessible, if the system gets compromised.

Comment: It also depends upon other factors such as what operating system these will be installed on, if a VM hypervisor will be exposing these interfaces to guest VM's and in what mode (NAT/Bridge/etc), and if traffic will be forwarded across any of them. If your using this on a Linux system this can be controlled with IP tables and sysctl rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,, that is not secure for your networks, your PC will be an entrance for other network if it got exploited, attacker can use PC as a zombie or even launch attacks to the three networks from it directly,,